# Hovering mouse to trigger animation in specifc distance from the edge in html via CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply a sliding animation on the box I created via  with some help from  css. The box is hidden at first but when the mouse hovers to the that area, the box will slide to its position. Because the box is big 600px, I tried the following to trigger the animation when the mouse is pointed at about 40 px from the edge of the browser:

CSS:

```
.lumpia-wrapper {
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 100%;    
   height: 100%; 
}


.box {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px
    background-color=blue;
}

#reveal  {
    position:absolute;
    top:-100%;
   transition: 5s;
}

.box2{
    width: 40px;
    height: 600px; 
   border: 4px solid black;
}

.box2:hover ~ .box:hover #reveal{
    top:0;
    transition: 5s;
}
```

HTML:

**...**

```
<div class=lumpia-wrapper>
<div class="box" id="reveal>Once upon the time...</div>
<div class="box2></div>
```

**...**

IT Did not work...

What have I done wrong? Is there something missing to make it work?

Comment: You are missing some quotes in your HTML, is that what your actual code is like? `<div class="box2>` should be `<div class="box2">` for example

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to add them to the actual code, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Is .box2 inside of .box or is it added afterwards? You should tidy up your markup. (`background-color=blue` also should be written `background-color: blue`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were several HTML errors. Make sure all tags are closed out, and all attributes are using quotes. The CSS was mostly correct, but unfortunately the way you were using `:hover` wont work. CSS has no way to select a previous sibling, you'll have to reorder the elements like below

This solution may work for you: **[EXAMPLE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/Canzv/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="lumpia-wrapper">
    <div class="box2"></div>
    <div id="reveal">Once upon the time...</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.lumpia-wrapper {
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 100%;    
   height: 100%; 
}

#reveal  {
    position:absolute;
    top: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: lightblue;
    transition: all 1s;
}
#reveal:hover{
    top: 0%;
}

.box2{
    width: 40px;
    height: 600px; 
   border: 4px solid black;
}

.box2:hover + #reveal{
    top: 0%;
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

Comment: Whoah! It worked! So that's why they always told me to clean,order and close html tags, I really thought that it doesn't affect the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I think the ~ selector only works if selected element is after the element.

If you want to select something directly inside use ">" if right next to "+"

HTML

```
<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box">Once upon the time...</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    display:none;
}

.box2{
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px; 
    border: 4px solid black;
}

.box2:hover ~ .box{
    display:block;
}
```

See this fiddle for solution: http://jsfiddle.net/rgJ82/